# What is the equivalent word for "compile" in an interpreted language?

Tags: terminology, lua

(I was encouraged to ask this [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/69549/what-is-the-equivalent-word-for-compile-in-an-interpreted-language) here.)

In C, we say:

> GCC *compiles* `foo.c`.

For interpreters (such as Lua), what is the equivalent verb?

> The Lua interpreter ____________ `foo.lua`.

When I write instructions for users of my Lua script, I often say:

> Run the interpreter on `foo.lua`.

I think this can be said more succinctly:

> *Interpret* (or *Translate*) `foo.lua`.

but that sounds awkward for some reason (perhaps because I'm unsure of its correctness). I can't really say *compile* because users may confuse it with the usage of the [Lua compiler](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/luac.html) when I actually mean the [Lua interpreter](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/lua.html).

Comment: What's wrong with "interprets"? I'm pretty sure that's a valid verb.

Comment: Please don't cross post. If you think that you've got the wrong site, flag the post so it can be migrated.

Comment: @ChrisF We closed his question on EL&U and this one is linked in the comments.

Comment: Take a look at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_(computing)

Comment: Are you sure _any_ of these answers are correct?  'Cause in general there is no direct equivalent of `compile` for interpreted languages - there is no executable file that gets created.  (Yeah, I know about `*.pyc` and so on, but I'm talking about _in general_)  Or is Lua different?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In addition to the obvious *interprets*, you could say that the interpreter *runs* or *executes* some code.

Comment: _"interprets"_ and _"runs"_ seem to be the most popular suggestions. I chose _"runs"_ because it sounds better in: "The Lua interpreter runs `foo.lua`"

Comment: I avoid using words like "execute" with non-techies, for the same reason I avoid using the term "fatal error".

Comment: @KristopherJohnson I suppose it might be important to be sensitive in that respect in certain contexts, but *to carry out* is a well-known meaning of *execute*, and it's often used in that sense. One executes a financial transaction or a legal document; people know that execution is as important as planning; the police execute a warrant.

Answer (score 17):

I have always thought along these lines:

> A compiler compiles code.
>
> An interpreter interprets code.

So I would say interprets.

Answer (score 4):

"Interprets" or "runs" are, I think, the two most natural verbs. Maybe "executes".

Comment: "runs" definitely makes sense in *nix land, since the [hashbang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashbang) can make scripts transparently runnable as if they were compiled programs.  Not sure if Windows has an equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds awkward because compilers and interpreters are really different things.

You can say "run the compiler" to get the binary and maybe deploy the application but you cannot say "run the interpreter" to produce binary and deploy it. So you cannot compare them.

Interpret is the right word.